# Как сделать что бы FloatingActionButton убирался при работе SearchView

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

Имеется Java код:

```
public class SphereActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MenuItem searchMenuItem;
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    public FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sphere);
        getAllItems();
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    }

    private void getAllItems() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.sphere);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_button);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sphere_menu, menu);
        MenuItem mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearch.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_text));
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //поиск происходит тут
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    //Обработка нажатий кнопок на Toolbar'е
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent i;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_profile:
                i = new Intent(SphereActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                i = new Intent(SphereActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

И код XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SphereActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            style="@style/ToolBar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tool_bar">
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:rippleColor="@color/b_accent_light"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы при появлении клавиатуры(поиск в SearchView) проподала кнопка FloatingActionButton

Comment: Делать ее невидимой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант. Этот метод будет срабатывать, при клике на иконку поиска, т.е при открытии `SearchView`.

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            floatingActionButton.hide();
        }
    });
```

`floatingActionButton.hide();` это же вы можете использовать в

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //поиск происходит тут
            floatingActionButton.hide();
            return false;
        }
```

Тогда `FloatingActionButton` будет скрываться при подтверждении поиска

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, но проблема не закрыта.Пользователь все еще может попасть в ситуацию где во время использование клавиатуры кнопка будет "уезжать вверх" вместе с ней.Можете подсказать что делать?

Comment: @FLYFOX2058 в каких случаях это происходит?